# OpenVPN service is not working on Ubuntu MATE

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I have used these [instructions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22688/openvpn-as-a-background-process) to setup a VPN service. However, the service does not start. After I execute

```
sudo service openvpn start
```

nothing happens. It shows no error and just returns the normal prompt. If I check my IP with the browser I can still see my original IP. I have also tried different suffixes for the configuration file like `*.ovpn` and `*.conf`.

Using openvpn from CLI directly, e.g.,

```
sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/us1.ovpn --auth-user-pass /path/to/password.file
```

does work, but I would also like to start it as service.

What am I missing?

The configuration file I am using is:

```
client
dev tun1
proto tcp
remote 198.7.62.204 443
remote us1.vpnbook.com 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 3
cipher AES-128-CBC
fast-io
pull
route-delay 2
redirect-gateway
<certificate info> ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Ubuntu mate? If it is 15.10 or later (IIRC) then it is a systemd based distro and you need to configure appropriately.

Here are details on how to do that from an [askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730355/start-openvpn-as-a-service-ubuntu-15-10/736402#736402) 
. Note that I edited that answer, and don't have edit privileges on that site, so the old version may be at the url. You will need to modify it to use your conf file.

> Using 15.10 and systemd, services work a bit differently. First, you
>   need to create a systemd unit file at
>   /usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@service and paste the following
>   contents into it:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On %I
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
PrivateTmp=true
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/openvpn/%i.pid
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --writepid /var/run/openvpn/%i.pid --cd /etc/openvpn/ --config %i.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

> Then, when you want to start the service, simply run:
>
> systemctl start openvpn@myopenvpn.service If you would like to add it
>   to system startup, you can configure systemd to start it during boot
>   (when at run level multiuser aka 3) with these commands:

```
systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl enable openvpn@myopenvpn.service
```

> You can check the status of the service at any time with:

```
 sudo systemctl status openvpn@myopenvpn.service
```

Alternatively, regardless of version, you can use a legacy approach as outlined [here](http://www.htpcguides.com/autoconnect-private-internet-access-vpn-boot-linux/).

Or even more simply just put your command that is working interactively in the /etc/rc.local file and make that file executable. Remember that in the rc.local file you have to use full paths to the executable, ie openvpn, as it doesn't have a fully populated PATH environmental variable.

.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It worked, though. Thanks.